# What is the next step in my test class?

Tags: unit-test

This is probably going to be a first of a few questions. I am trying to make a test class for my vf controller. For some reason, I do not grasp how the whole unit testing works. I understand why but I am not sure how to proceed. I am hoping that I will 'get it' once I try it a couple of times.

1) I click on code coverage in the developer console and it stays at zero. How do I know if it is working?

2) Below is a pathetic beginning to a test class. This issue is that I am not sure what is the next step. I will post the code under the test class.

Here is the test class

```
@isTest
private class test_Training_Students 
{
    static testMethod void test_selectStudents()
    {
        SearchIntervieweesExtension ext;
        ApexPages.standardController sc;

        Account account = new Account();
        account.Name='Jasmine Training Ctr';
        insert account;

        Contact contactInterviewee = new Contact();
        contactInterviewee.FirstName = 'test747';
        contactInterviewee.LastName = 'test747';
        contactInterviewee.Accountid = account.id;
        contactInterviewee.RecordTypeid='012G0000001IiGfIAK';
        contactInterviewee.Active_Candidate__c=true;
        insert contactInterviewee;

        Contact contactInterviewer = new Contact();
        contactInterviewer.FirstName = 'test2';
        contactInterviewer.LastName = 'test2';
        //contactInterviewer.Account = account;
        contactInterviewer.Accountid = account.id;
        insert contactInterviewer;

        Training__c tr = New Training__c();
        tr.Name = 'Alyiah 1';
        tr.Shaliach__c = '003G000002Futim';
        tr.Training_Resource__c='a1ZG000000CoOui';

        Training__c tr2 = New Training__c();
        tr2.Name = 'Alyiah 2';
        tr2.Shaliach__c = '003G000002Futim';
        tr2.Training_Resource__c='a1ZG000000CoOui';

         Test.startTest();

         Test.stopTest();

//          static testMethod void test_Training_Students()
//          {


//          }

    }

}
```

Here is the code

```
public with sharing class cls_Training_Students {



    // Const
    private static final string RECORD_TYPE_Teacher = 'Teacher';    
    private static final string OBJECT_NAME_FOR_CONTACT_ROLES = 'Additional_Contact_Role__c';

    public Boolean refreshPage { get; set; }
    public String redirectUrl {public get; private set;}
    private ApexPages.StandardController stdController;

    // Inner class
    public class selectedPerson{
        public boolean isSelected {get;set;}
        //public Contact contact {get;set;}
        public Additional_Contact_Role__c contactR {get;set;}
    }

    // Params
    public String currentContacts_CSV {get;set;}
    public set<Id> currentContactIds_Set {get;set;}
    public list<selectedPerson> selectedContacts_List {get;set;}
    public list<selectedPerson> completeContacts4VF_List {get;set;}
    private Training_Resource__c currentQ = new Training_Resource__c();
    private list<Contact> contactsFromQ_List = new list<Contact>();
    private list<Contact> completeContacts_List = new list<Contact>();
    /// moving to be based on Contact Role
    private list<Additional_Contact_Role__c> completeContacts_List2 = new list<Additional_Contact_Role__c>();
    private list<Additional_Contact_Role__c> contactsFromQ_List2 = new list<Additional_Contact_Role__c  >();


    // vars
    list<String> splitContactIds = new list<String>();
    Id shalichRTId = null;

    public cls_Training_Students(ApexPages.StandardController controller){

        this.stdController = controller;

        currentQ.Id = controller.getId();
        currentQ = [Select Id, Selected_Contacts_Ids_List__c From Training_Resource__c Where Id = :currentQ.Id];

        shalichRTId = [select id from RecordType where sobjecttype =:OBJECT_NAME_FOR_CONTACT_ROLES  and Name =:RECORD_TYPE_Teacher limit 1].Id;

        redirectUrl = '/' + currentQ.Id;
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        currentContacts_CSV = (currentQ.Selected_Contacts_Ids_List__c != '' ? currentQ.Selected_Contacts_Ids_List__c : '');
        currentContactIds_Set = new set<Id>();
        selectedContacts_List = new list<selectedPerson>();
        selectedPerson sp = new selectedPerson();
        completeContacts4VF_List = new list<selectedPerson>();

        // CSV to list
        if (currentContacts_CSV != null && currentContacts_CSV != ''){
            splitContactIds = currentContacts_CSV.split('[,]');
            for (String cId:splitContactIds){
                currentContactIds_Set.add(cId);
            }
        }

        //  query test
        Set<Id> relevantContactsIds_Set = new Set<Id>();
        // Select Contact__c, Contact_Name__c, a.Supervisor_Name__c, a.RecordTypeId, a.Months_in_Shlichut__c, a.Melaveh_Name__c, a.JAFI_Region__c, a.Id, a.Coordinator_Name__c, a.Active__c From Additional_Contact_Role__c a
        Map<Id,Additional_Contact_Role__c> crMap = new Map<Id,Additional_Contact_Role__c>([select contact__c from Additional_Contact_Role__c where recordTypeId = :shalichRTId ]);

        for (Id acrId : crMap.keySet())
        {
            relevantContactsIds_Set.add(crMap.get(acrId).Contact__c);
        }

         system.debug('relevantContactsIds_Set +++++++++'  + relevantContactsIds_Set.size());
         system.debug('crMap +++++++++'  + crMap.size());
        //  query test end

        contactsFromQ_List = [Select Id, Name, JAFI_Region__c From Contact Where Id IN :currentContactIds_Set];
        contactsFromQ_List2 = [Select Contact__c, Contact_Name__c, a.Supervisor_Name__c, 
                                                                            a.RecordTypeId, a.Months_in_Shlichut__c, a.Melaveh_Name__c, a.JAFI_Region__c, a.Id, 
                                                                            a.Coordinator_Name__c, a.Active__c 
                                                                            From Additional_Contact_Role__c a 
                                                                            Where a.RecordTypeId = :shalichRTId 
                                                                            AND Contact__c IN :currentContactIds_Set];
        Integer maxList = 999-contactsFromQ_List.size();
        if(currentContactIds_Set.size() < 1){
            completeContacts_List = [Select Id, Name, JAFI_Region__c From Contact Where Id IN :relevantContactsIds_Set limit :maxList];
            completeContacts_List2 = [Select Contact__c, Contact_Name__c, a.Supervisor_Name__c, 
                                                                            a.RecordTypeId, a.Months_in_Shlichut__c, a.Melaveh_Name__c, a.JAFI_Region__c, a.Id, 
                                                                            a.Coordinator_Name__c, a.Active__c 
                                                                            From Additional_Contact_Role__c a 
                                                                            Where a.RecordTypeId = :shalichRTId 
                                                                            //AND Contact__c IN :currentContactIds_Set
                                                                            limit :maxList];
        }
        else {
            completeContacts_List = [Select Id, Name, JAFI_Region__c From Contact Where Id IN :relevantContactsIds_Set and Id NOT IN :currentContactIds_Set limit :maxList];
            completeContacts_List2 = [Select Contact__c, Contact_Name__c, a.Supervisor_Name__c, 
                                                                            a.RecordTypeId, a.Months_in_Shlichut__c, a.Melaveh_Name__c, a.JAFI_Region__c, a.Id, 
                                                                            a.Coordinator_Name__c, a.Active__c 
                                                                            From Additional_Contact_Role__c a 
                                                                            Where a.RecordTypeId = :shalichRTId 
                                                                            AND Contact__c NOT IN :currentContactIds_Set 
                                                                            limit :maxList];
            }


        // Prep the contacts lists
        for (Additional_Contact_Role__c cr : contactsFromQ_List2){
            sp = new selectedPerson();
            sp.isSelected = true;
            sp.contactR = cr;
            completeContacts4VF_List.add(sp);
        }

        for (Additional_Contact_Role__c cr : completeContacts_List2){
            sp = new selectedPerson();
            sp.isSelected = false;
            sp.contactR = cr;
            completeContacts4VF_List.add(sp);
        }
    }

    public PageReference clearAllContacts()
    {
        currentQ.Selected_Contacts_Ids_List__c = '';

        try{
            update currentQ;
            refreshPage = true;
            //redirectUrl = '/' + currentQ.Id;//controller.getId().getUrl();
             init();
        } catch(DmlException e) {
            return new PageReference('/apex/DMLError');
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return new PageReference('/apex/Error');
        } 
        return null; //return new PageReference('/apex/Search_Interviewees?Id=' + currentQ.Id);

    }

    public PageReference saveAllContacts()
    {
        list<String> returnedSelectedPersonsID_StringList = new list<String>();
        for (selectedPerson sp : completeContacts4VF_List){
                returnedSelectedPersonsID_StringList.add(sp.ContactR.Contact__c);
        }

        String tempCSV = '';

        if(returnedSelectedPersonsID_StringList.size() > 0){

            for(String Id : returnedSelectedPersonsID_StringList){
                // First selected person
                if (tempCSV == ''){
                    tempCSV = Id;
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    tempCSV += ',' + Id;
                }
            }
        }

        currentQ.Selected_Contacts_Ids_List__c = tempCSV;
        system.debug('tempCSV +++++++++'  + tempCSV);
        try{
            update currentQ;
            refreshPage = true;
            //redirectUrl = '/' + currentQ.Id;//stdController.view().getUrl();
            init();

        } catch(DmlException e) {
            return new PageReference('/apex/DMLError');
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return new PageReference('/apex/Error');
        } 
        return null; //new PageReference('/apex/Search_Interviewees?Id=' + currentQ.Id);

    }

    public PageReference updateContactSelection()
    {


        string cId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cId');
        string state = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('isChecked');
        if (state == 'true')
            // if this is the first selection
            if (currentQ.Selected_Contacts_Ids_List__c == null || currentQ.Selected_Contacts_Ids_List__c == '')
                currentQ.Selected_Contacts_Ids_List__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cId');
            else
                currentQ.Selected_Contacts_Ids_List__c += ',' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cId');
        else
        {
            if (currentQ.Selected_Contacts_Ids_List__c.startsWith(cId))
                currentQ.Selected_Contacts_Ids_List__c = currentQ.Selected_Contacts_Ids_List__c.replace( cId+',','');
            else
                currentQ.Selected_Contacts_Ids_List__c = currentQ.Selected_Contacts_Ids_List__c.replace(','+ cId,'');
        }

        try{
            update currentQ;
        } catch(DmlException e) {
            return new PageReference('/apex/DMLError');
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return new PageReference('/apex/Error');
        } 
        return null;
    }

public PageReference addTraining()
    {
// This method save the selected contacts to the training__c object
// It determines the list by looking at the field Selected_Contacts_Ids_List__c
        init();

        if ( currentQ.Selected_Contacts_Ids_List__c == Null ||  currentQ.Selected_Contacts_Ids_List__c == '')
        {
            List <training__c> rd = [Select ID FROM training__c WHERE Training_Resource__c = :currentQ.Id];
            delete rd;
            return null;
        }

            Training__c[] ts = new Training__c[]{};  

            if(currentQ.Selected_Contacts_Ids_List__c.containsNone(',')  )
            {
                ts.add(new Training__c(Teacher__c = currentContacts_CSV,Training_Resource__c=currentQ.Id));                            
            }else
            {    
                for (String cId:splitContactIds)
                    {
                        ts.add(new Training__c(Teacher__c = cId,Training_Resource__c=currentQ.Id));                
                    }
            }

            List <training__c> rd = [Select ID FROM training__c WHERE Training_Resource__c = :currentQ.Id];
            delete rd;

            insert ts;  
            init();

        return null;

    }       


}
```

Comment: I would advise against hardcoding record type id as they are specific to a Salesforce Org, so when you deployed the changes from a sandbox to production it would probably either throw an error on deployment or fail to execute correctly.  Better to do a lookup on the Record Type using the Developer name to retrieve the Id.

Answer (score 3):

```
@isTest
private class test_Training_Students{

static void setup() {
/*
You can put here the logic you included in your question to create necessary records
*/
}

static testMethod void testConstructor() {
    setup();
    // perform any additional stuff you need before calling constructor
    cls_Training_Students controller;
    Test.startTest();
        controller = new cls_Training_Students ( sc );
    Test.stopTest();
    // perform all asserts needed to make sure everything which should be populated is populated on constructor call
}

static testMethod void testClearAllContacts() {
    setup();
    // perform any additional stuff you do manually on the page before clicking button which runs this action clearAllContacts
    cls_Training_Students controller = new cls_Training_Students ( sc );
    Test.startTest();
        controller.clearAllContacts();
    Test.stopTest();
    // perform all asserts needed to make sure everything which should be populated is populated on this action call
}

static testMethod void testSaveAllContacts() {
    setup();
    // perform any additional stuff you do manually on the page before clicking button which runs this action saveAllContacts
    cls_Training_Students controller = new cls_Training_Students ( sc );
    Test.startTest();
        controller.saveAllContacts();
    Test.stopTest();
    // perform all asserts needed to make sure everything which should be populated is populated on this action call
}

static testMethod void testUpdateContactSelection() {
    setup();
    // perform any additional stuff you do manually on the page before clicking button which runs this action updateContactSelection
    cls_Training_Students controller = new cls_Training_Students ( sc );
    Test.startTest();
        controller.updateContactSelection();
    Test.stopTest();
    // perform all asserts needed to make sure everything which should be populated is populated on this action call
}

static testMethod void testAddTraining() {
    setup();
    // perform any additional stuff you do manually on the page before clicking button which runs this action addTraining
    cls_Training_Students controller = new cls_Training_Students ( sc );
    Test.startTest();
        controller.addTraining();
    Test.stopTest();
    // perform all asserts needed to make sure everything which should be populated is populated on this action call

}
}
```